# identify noisy tab across multiple chrome windows?

Tags: google-chrome

If I start hearing some music/sound/noise while i'm browsing in chrome, and I want to know which tab it is .  And I have multiple chrome windows each with multiple tabs, then how can I identify which it is?

I can see that the speaker tray icon in windows 7 doesn't do it, it only shows the currently active tab in the currently active window, even if another tab in another window is making the noise.

Comment: **`Shift+Esc`** and open up the browsers' task manager....you can see all the processes running on your browser. Hearing _music/sound_ ...so, possibly you might be able to see a fluctuation in the **_network_** tab in the Task **`Manager`**.

Comment: @Rakitić  thanks, that might work.. I wonder though if it's backgroudn audio and the audio has fully loaded then maybe not.. i'll have to try it next time it happens. But I see it does work for youtube videos, so it's promising.  I can see a fluctuating tab hitting top of the list in network usage from time to time and I can double click it. So that seems to work for youtube videos, at least if they're not fully loaded, don't know if once they're loaded, ditto for plain audio, but  certainly promising, i'll have to test it when it next happens

Answer (score 0):

On the right side of each tab, if it is making noise there will be a little speaker icon.  Of course, you'll have to look at all your tabs to see it.

Comment: I meant to mention that one in the question.. it's not that feasiible if I don't even know which chrome window it is, to go through every window and then every tab within every window

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> and open up the browser's **Task manager**, so you can see all the *processes* running on your browser. Hearing music/sound ...so, possibly you might be able to see a *fluctuation* in the **Network** tab in the **`Task Manager`**.

[image: c#]

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of Chrome you can simply look for the speaker icon next to the offending tab. In case of too many tabs, you can use the excellent open source tab switching extension [Quicktabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-tabs/jnjfeinjfmenlddahdjdmgpbokiacbbb?hl=en), which allows you to find noisy tabs by searching for `<))`.

However, the above solution won't help you identify tabs playing a short notification sound (like Discord for example). The solution in that case is to use the `chrome://media-internals` internal page and identify the offending tab by following the procedure in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1447666/what-chrome-tab-has-just-made-noise/1584126#1584126).