# What Chrome tab has just made noise?

Tags: google-chrome

I have many windows and tabs open, and once in a while, one of them makes a "click" noise. It's just a one-second sound, so there's no time to visually scan the tab bar for the speaker icon.

Does Chromium have some sort of "event logs" [hidden internal Chrome URL](https://gist.github.com/KamranMackey/4bec5630e040be4dcbbe460bb5a1a0ad), that might show what tab played that audio?

I've looked in `chrome://media-internals/` -> Audio, but those "controllers" did not always reflect the tab that last played sound.

Answer (score 6):

Go to the `Players` tab of `chrome://media-internals` and look for your culprit at the bottom of the list. You can click on an entry and see more info about it in the `Player Properties` section further down. Usually you can simply find the url of the mp3 clip and paste it in a new browser tab to verify it's the offending sound.

Comment: I love this answer because it is not OS-specific.